# scalac compile yields "object apache is not a member of package org"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My code is:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
```

It can run in interactive mode, but when I use scalac to compile it, I got the following error message:

> object apache is not a member of package org

This seems to be the problem of path, but I do not know exactly how to configure the path.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to specify the path of libraries used when compiling your Scala code. This is usually not done manually, but using a build tool such as Maven or sbt. You can find a minimal sbt setup at http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications

Comment: My `Play` project is built using `sbt`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447732/how-to-integrate-spark-with-play-framework-in-intellij-idea. why?

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue because I had the wrong scope for my spark dependency in my `pom.xml` file. This is **wrong**:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${spark.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope> <!-- will not be available during compile phase -->
</dependency>
```

Changing `test` `->` `provided` **will work** and will not include spark in your uberjar which is what you will almost certainly want:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${spark.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: precision? assumptions made here, what file are you editing?

Comment: updated my answer. Thanks @user1796185!

Answer (score 3):

One easy way (if you're using the Play Framework) is to look up the `LibraryDependacy` in the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/), choose the version, [choose SBT](https://www.evernote.com/l/ArGSWizJ-0lIl4ZbhKgx-5eAoYU4YuasVWo) and then add it to the bottom of your `project/build.sbt` file, like so:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.2"
```

Afterwards, you'll want to enter `reload` into the sbt console and then `compile`.   This can feel a little foreign if you're coming from `pip` or `js` but the Maven Repo is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue in the `sbt interactive` session.

Resolved the is by simple executing `reload` in the session.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue when running scala wordcount program on spark frame work.
I was using eclipse as IDE and maven as build tool.
I just removed the scope of spark frame work in POM file from "test"-->"provided", like below. It worked. 
provided