# scala console error: object apache is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying the code proposed here:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/mllib-ensembles.html#classification

using the Scala console (Scala version = Scala code runner version 2.10.4), and get the following error:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest
<console>:8: error: object apache is not a member of package org
           import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest
                      ^
```

I then followed the advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28270036/190791) and tried to build a simple self-contained application, but ran into a different problem:

```
root@sd:~/simple# sbt package
[info] Set current project to Simple Project (in build file:/root/simple/)
[info] Updating {file:/root/simple/}default-c5720e...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10.4;1.2.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10.4;1.2.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /root/.ivy2/local/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10.4/1.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10.4/1.2.0/spark-core_2.10.4-1.2.0.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10.4;1.2.0: not found
```

Can anyone advise what I could try?

Comment: you are not using the spark shell!

Comment: @eliasah I am getting the same error in the spark shell.

Comment: did you download a pre-compiled dist? scala console will definitly not work unless you add the spark jars into your console while launching it

Comment: @eliasah I installed spark by following the instructions from here: http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/10/31/install-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04/  (so I used scala-2.10.4.tgz and spark-1.1.0.tgz).

Comment: Go to the official spark page, the documentation about building or using it  is complete. [http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/)

Comment: @eliasah Ok, will try that. What is the easiest way to install on Ubuntu? a pre-built or with the source code?

Comment: I'll definitly go with the pre-built for dev and then you might need a ec2 cluster for prod.

Comment: @tucson I can't see your sbt configuration, but it is possible that you specified "groupID %% artifactID % revision" instead of "groupID % artifactID % revision". Notice the difference in % after groupId. If there are two %% then, it will try to fetch scala version, otherwise java version of dependency. Update your sbt depending on the type of package you want to import. I know this is a pretty old post, but thought I will try :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can find detailed steps in [this post](http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/04/01/a-standalone-spark-application-in-scala/) how to write self contained Spark application using SBT in Scala. In sbt configuration file you should specify the dependent libraries.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.1",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.2.1")
```

Then compile using following command

```
sbt package
```