# How to create SparkSession with Hive support (fails with "Hive classes are not found")?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting an error while trying to run the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate();        
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.enableHiveSupport(SparkSession.scala:778)
    at com.training.hivetest.App.main(App.java:21)
```

How can it be resolved?

Comment: Import the spark hive maven dependency in you pom.xml, 
add the properties tag in your pom and put global variables each for spark.version and scala.version and substitute these variables in your dependencies to avoid version conflicts.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Add following dependency to your maven project.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have spark-hive_2.11-2.0.1.jar but I still get the error ( I just manually added the jar to the class path - did not add dependency to Maven)

Comment: @Sam-T Are you able to import "org.apache.spark.sql.hive.*;" in your java class? Did you try adding it to maven and then update maven project?

Comment: Also need to make sure you are having same artifactId and version number as you are having for spark-core and spark-sql

Comment: This did not help me, in my case it was due to running this via the JVM (java) instead of the provided Spark script /bin/spark-submit.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61050495/8366477

Comment: it doesn't work. I tried `--jar spark-hive_2.11-2.4.4.jar` and maven dependency. both are not working.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** You have to make sure that Spark SQL's `spark-hive` dependency and all transitive dependencies are available at **runtime** on the CLASSPATH of a Spark SQL application (not build time that is simply required for compilation only).

---

In other words, you have to have `org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder` and `org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf` classes on the CLASSPATH of the Spark application (which has little to do with sbt or maven).

The former `HiveSessionStateBuilder` is part of `spark-hive` dependency (incl. all the transitive dependencies).

The latter `HiveConf` is part of `hive-exec` dependency (that is a transitive dependency of the above `spark-hive` dependency).

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into the source code, and found that despite **HiveSessionState**(in spark-hive), another class **HiveConf** is also needed to initiate SparkSession. And **HiveConf** is not contained in spark-hive*jar， maybe you can find it in hive related jars and put it in your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I could resolve it by adding following dependencies. (I resolved this list by referring [compile dependencies section of spark-hive_2.11 mvn repository page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.11/2.1.0)):

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.calcite</groupId>
            <artifactId>calcite-avatica</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.calcite</groupId>
            <artifactId>calcite-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spark-project.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.spark2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spark-project.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.spark2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

where scala.binary.version = 2.11 and spark.version = 2.1.0

```
 <properties>
      <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
      <spark.version>2.1.0</spark.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Why do you need to add these as explicit dependencies? These are all anyways compiled into spark-hive jar right?

Answer (score 1):

For **SBT** Use 

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.1.0"
```

We have used **Spark-Core-2.1.0** and **Spark-SQL-2.1.0**

Answer (score 1):

While all the top answers are correct, and still you are facing issues, then remember the error described in the question can still occur even though you have mentioned the jars in your pom.

In order to resolve this issue, please make sure the version of all your dependencies should be same and as a standard practice, maintain a global variable for spark version and scala version, and substitute these values to avoid any conflict due to different versions.

Just for the reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx.rehi</groupId>
    <artifactId>Maven9211</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <scala.version>2.12</scala.version>
    <spark.version>2.4.4</spark.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to check

> Include dependencies with "Provided" scope

under my **Run/Debug Configuration** in intellij

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are running your jar via the spark-submit script:

```
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit <settings> <your-jar-name>
```

which is a script that loads in the required classes and provides scala support before executing your jar.

Also as others have mentioned please ensure that you have loaded in the required dependency as well.

**Example: Running a Spark Session**

```
pom.xml
---
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

Test.java
---
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("FeatureExtractor")
    .config("spark.master", "local")
    .config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", false)
    .config("spark.submit.deployMode", "client")
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hivemetastore:9083")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate();
```

So then to execute this code via Spark:

```
bin/spark-submit \
--class com.TestExample \
--executor-memory 1G \
--total-executor-cores 2 \
test.jar
```

Thank you to @lamber-ken who helped me with this issue.

For more information:

[Spark Documentation: Submitting Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

[Exception Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found](https://github.com/apache/incubator-hudi/issues/1487#issuecomment-609472838)

Answer (score 0):

[Updating my Answer] This answer on StackOverflow is right - [answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28270036/7538823).

I also faced issues building and running Spark with HiveSupport. Based on the above answer I did the following in my Spark 2.12.8 project.

1. Updated my build.sbt to the below content
2. Manually removed the files in .idea/libraries
3. Clicked 'Refresh all sbt projects' button in SBT Shell window (I am using intellij)

I can now run the project without any issues.

```
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.4.2" % "provided",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.3" % Test
)
```

Answer (score -1):

My full list of dependencies for Spark 2.4.1 is here

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-hive_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.calcite</groupId>
      <artifactId>calcite-avatica</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.calcite</groupId>
      <artifactId>calcite-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.12.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spark-project.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1.spark2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spark-project.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1.spark2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.7</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.7.1</version>
  </dependency>


  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.7</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.janino/janino -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
      <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.9</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.janino/commons-compiler -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.9</version>
  </dependency>
```