# enableHiveSupport throws error in java spark code

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a very simple application that is trying to read an orc file from /src/main/resources using spark.  I keep getting this error:

> Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.

I have tried adding the dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

as recommended here: [Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444493/unable-to-instantiate-sparksession-with-hive-support-because-hive-classes-are-no)

however, no matter what I have added, I still get this error.

I am running this on my local windows machine through NetBeans IDE.

my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().orc("/src/main/resources/testdir");        
        spark.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you leave NetBeans IDE for a moment, build the package (using `sbt package` or similar) and `spark-submit`? Looks like an issue with Netbeans IDE not Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running in `IDE`, I recommend to use `.master("local")` in you `SparkSession` object.

**Next important point is that the version of spark-hive should match with spark-core and spark-sql versions**. for safety you can define dependency as

```
<properties>
    <spark.version>2.0.0</spark.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! adding the .master("local") did the trick!!

Comment: @M.Uk Happy to see your problem resolved. :) you can upvote too if the answer helped you .