# enableHiveSupport() function throwing error in scala spark code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

While tring to enable hive support in scala code, `enableHiveSupport()` function throws the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.

The error looks similar to the discussion in the following threads (which are Java-based):

[enableHiveSupport throws error in java spark code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153660/enablehivesupport-throws-error-in-java-spark-code)

[How to create SparkSession with Hive support (fails with "Hive classes are not found")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444493/how-to-create-sparksession-with-hive-support-fails-with-hive-classes-are-not-f)

Despite trying the solutions given in the above mentioned threads, the issue still persists.

I am using Intellij IDE.

My Scala class looks something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

class Reader {
  def read_csv(file_name: String, spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    print("In read_csv\n")
    val csv_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(file_name)
    csv_df
  }


}

object DataframeOps{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .config("spark.master", "local")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .appName("DataframeExample")
      .getOrCreate();
    val obj = new Reader();
    val data = obj.read_csv("./src/main/data/iris/Iris.csv", spark)
    data.show()
  }
}
```

My build.sbt file is as follows:

```
name := "Scala Spark"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.4.5" % "runtime"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.12.10"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.4.5" % "provided"
```

I tried rebuilding the project, clearing the .idea/libraries, tried removing and adding the hive dependency, checked versions of dependencies, added .master("local") but nothing seems to work.

However, I am able to import hive libraries with following command:

`import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._`

Which seems strange given the fact that the error suggests that hive classes weren't found.

Comment: `"spark-hive" % "2.4.5" % "provided"` means that this library won't be included in the final build, but is present in place, where you're going to deploy your library. So sbt would download classes for local use, but won't include then when packaging the project. Could you try removing `provided` in `spark-hive`?

Comment: @RayanRal Your solution worked like a charm. I had picked up the sbt dependency line from mavenrepository.com as is.

Comment: @RayanRal can you please post your solution as an answer to my question so that i can accept it?