# How to configure Spark 2.4 correctly with user-provided Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I'd like to use Spark 2.4.5 (the current stable Spark version) and Hadoop 2.10 (the current stable Hadoop version in the 2.x series). Further I need to access HDFS, Hive, S3, and Kafka.

http://spark.apache.org provides Spark 2.4.5 pre-built and bundled with either Hadoop 2.6 or Hadoop 2.7.
Another option is to use the Spark *with user-provided Hadoop*, so I tried that one.

As a consequence of using *with user-provided Hadoop*, Spark does not include Hive libraries either.
There will be an error, like here: [How to create SparkSession with Hive support (fails with "Hive classes are not found")?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39444493/2390083)

When I add the *spark-hive* dependency to the *spark-shell* (*spark-submit* is affected as well) by using

```
spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.4.5
```

in *spark-defaults.conf*, I get this error:

```
20/02/26 11:20:45 ERROR spark.SparkContext: 
Failed to add file:/root/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.avro_avro-mapred-1.8.2.jar to Spark environment
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar /root/.ivy2/jars/org.apache.avro_avro-mapred-1.8.2.jar not found
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addJarFile$1(SparkContext.scala:1838)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addJar(SparkContext.scala:1868)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$11(SparkContext.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$new$11$adapted(SparkContext.scala:458)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:106)
```

because *spark-shell* cannot handle classifiers together with bundle dependencies, see https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/21339 and https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17416

A workaround for the classifier probleme looks like this:

```
$ cp .../.ivy2/jars/org.apache.avro_avro-mapred-1.8.2-hadoop2.jar .../.ivy2/jars/org.apache.avro_avro-mapred-1.8.2.jar
```

but DevOps won't accept this.

The complete list of dependencies looks like this (I have added line breaks for better readability)

```
root@a5a04d888f85:/opt/spark-2.4.5/conf# cat spark-defaults.conf
spark.jars.packages=com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.9.10,
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.10,
org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.4.5,
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5,
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.10.0,
io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.5.0,
org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5,
mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18,
com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.3,
io.prestosql:presto-jdbc:307
```

(everything works - except for Hive)

- Is the combination of Spark 2.4.5 and Hadoop 2.10 used anywhere? How?
- How to combine *Spark 2.4.5 with user-provided Hadoop* and Hadoop 2.9 or 2.10 ?
- Is it necessary to build Spark to get around the Hive dependency problem ?

Comment: Curious about the comment regarding pre-built versions.  I only see prebuilt binaries for Hadoop 2.6 and Hadoop 2.7, but this suggest the availability is Hadoop 2.7 and Hadoop 2.8.  Was this an off-by-one error, or has something changed?

Comment: I want to upgrade my hadoop aws to 3.2. Currently stuck with spark dependency on hadoop 2.7. Is it possible to shade the hadoop aws? I will be using uber jar.

Comment: @Knight71 It might work in your case. Yet in my experience this normally leads to problems especially in case of AWS dependencies. It's exactly for this reason that I build Spark (with consistent) dependencies.

Comment: Spark cluster is in 2.2.1 with pre-built hadoop 2.7. It is not working since the 2.7 jars are already there in classpath. Getting ClassNotFound error for hadoop config.

Answer (score 5):

There does not seem to be an easy way to configure *Spark 2.4.5 with user-provided Hadoop* to use Hadoop 2.10.0

As my task actually was to minimize dependency problems, I have chosen to [compile Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html) 2.4.5 against Hadoop 2.10.0.

```
./dev/make-distribution.sh \
  --name hadoop-2.10.0 \
  --tgz \
  -Phadoop-2.7 -Dhadoop.version=hadoop-2.10.0 \
  -Phive -Phive-thriftserver \
  -Pyarn
```

Now Maven deals with the Hive dependencies/classifiers, and the resulting package is ready to be used.

In my personal opinion compiling Spark is actually easier than configuring the *Spark with-user-provided Hadoop*.

Integration tests so far have not shown any problems, Spark can access both HDFS and S3 (MinIO).

**Update 2021-04-08**

If you want to add support for Kubernetes, just add `-Pkubernetes` to the list of arguments

Comment: This approach seems sound.  I did the same with a target version of Hadoop 2.8.5 successfully.  For an extra measure of reassurance, I compared the versions of every override in any of Spark's build profile and found that they had not changed at all.  I suspect the same is true of Hadoop 2.10.0.  Setting -Dhadoop.verrsion does not appear to effect the compilation, only the dependencies that get bundled, which is what you are tweaking manually when you customize a `your-own-Hadoop` release by dropping in jars from a chosen hadoop version.  This just allows the build system do that work for you.

Comment: It also seems to be the documentation-provided method to build with a targeted Hadoop version.  It's worth scanning over these directions--otherwise you'll miss things like setting MAVEN_OPTS to account for the build's memory requirements!  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-hive-and-jdbc-support

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't want to run Spark-on-YARN -- start from bundle *"Spark 2.4.5 with Hadoop 2.7"* then cherry-pick the Hadoop libraries to upgrade from bundle *"Hadoop 2.10.x"*

1. Discard `spark-yarn` / `hadoop-yarn-*` / `hadoop-mapreduce-client-*` JARs because you won't need them, **except** `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` that is referenced by write operations on HDFS and S3 (cf. "MR commit procedure" V1 or V2)

   - you may also discard `spark-mesos` / `mesos-*` and/or `spark-kubernetes` / `kubernetes-*`  JARs depending on what you plan to run Spark on
   - you may also discard `spark-hive-thriftserver` and `hive-*` JARS if you don't plan to run a "thrift server" instance, **except** `hive-metastore` that is necessary for, as you might guess, managing the Metastore *(either a regular Hive Metastore service or an embedded Metastore inside the Spark session)*
2. Discard `hadoop-hdfs` / `hadoop-common` / `hadoop-auth` / `hadoop-annotations` / `htrace-core*` / `xercesImpl` JARs
3. Replace with `hadoop-hdfs-client` / `hadoop-common` / `hadoop-auth` / `hadoop-annotations` / `htrace-core*` / `xercesImpl` / `stax2-api` JARs from Hadoop 2.10 (under `common/`and `common/lib/`, or `hdfs/` and `hdfs/lib/`)
4. Add the S3A connector from Hadoop 2.10 i.e. `hadoop-aws` / `jets3t` / `woodstox-core` JARs (under `tools/lib/`)
5. download `aws-java-sdk` from Amazon (cannot be bundled with Hadoop because it's not an Apache license, I guess)
6. and finally, run a lot of tests...

That worked for me, after some trial-and-error -- with a caveat: I ran my tests against an S3-compatible storage system, but not against the "real" S3, and not against regular HDFS. And without a "real" Hive Metastore service, just the embedded in-memory & volatile Metastore that Spark runs by default.

---

For the record, the process is the same with Spark 3.0.0 previews and Hadoop 3.2.1, except that

- you also have to upgrade `guava`
- you don't have to upgrade `xercesImpl` nor `htrace-core` nor `stax2-api`
- you don't need `jets3t` any more
- you need to retain more `hadoop-mapreduce-client-*` JARs (probably because of the new "S3 committers")

Comment: Don't suppose you've a bash script to set this up? ;)

Comment: My _client_ owns that script... and they are quite stubborn about not sharing anything, for any reason.

Comment: Hmm. Rewrite said script in Ansible/Chef? :)

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. So indeed it's not easy. I will run some tests today, and give a feedback later.