# Python connecting to spark in standalone mode and accessing s3 with S3AFileSystem issues

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark, hadoop-plugins

**Setup**

- Spark `spark-2.4.5-bin-without-hadoop` configured with `hadoop-2.8.5`.
- Spark is running in standalone mode.
- PySpark application runs as a separate container and connects to the master from another container.

**What needs to happen?**

- PySpark application should be able to connect to AWS S3 bucket by using `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider`

**Attempted solution #1**

- Master, workers, and the PySpark application all have the following jars at `/`

```
hadoop-aws-2.8.5.jar
hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar 
aws-java-sdk-1.10.6.jar
jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar
jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
joda-time-2.9.4.jar
```

- PySpark application is configured the following way:

```py
builder = SparkSession.builder

builder = builder.config("spark.executor.userClassPathFirst", "true")
builder = builder.config("spark.driver.userClassPathFirst", "true")

class_path = "/hadoop-aws-2.8.5.jar:/hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar:/aws-java-sdk-1.10.6.jar:/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar:/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar:/jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar:/jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar:/joda-time-2.9.4.jar"
builder = builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", class_path)
builder = builder.config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", class_path)

builder = builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
builder = builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
builder = builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"))
builder = builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))
builder = builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token", os.environ.get("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"))
```

**Output**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil.hasKerberosTicket(Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z
....
```

- This was happening because `hadoop-auth` was missing. I downloaded `hadoop-auth` and got another error. It lead me to conclude that I would need to provide all the dependent jars.
- Instead of going manually through maven. I tried to import `hadoop-aws` into IntelliJ IDEA to see if it's going to import other dependencies and it gave me this  list: (Don't know if there is a `mvn` command that would do the same thing)

```
accessors-smart-1.2.jar
activation-1.1.jar
apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar
apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar
api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar
api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar
asm-3.1.jar
asm-5.0.4.jar
avro-1.7.4.jar
aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar
aws-java-sdk-kms-1.10.6.jar
aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
commons-math3-3.1.1.jar
commons-net-3.1.jar
curator-client-2.7.1.jar
curator-framework-2.7.1.jar
curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
guava-11.0.2.jar
hadoop-annotations-2.8.5.jar
hadoop-auth-2.8.5.jar
hadoop-aws-2.8.5.jar
hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar
htrace-core4-4.0.1-incubating.jar
httpclient-4.5.2.jar
httpcore-4.4.4.jar
jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-xc-1.8.3.jar
java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar
jersey-core-1.9.jar
jersey-json-1.9.jar
jersey-server-1.9.jar
jets3t-0.9.0.jar
jettison-1.1.jar
jetty-6.1.26.jar
jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar
jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
joda-time-2.9.4.jar
jsch-0.1.54.jar
json-smart-2.3.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
jsr305-3.0.0.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
netty-3.7.0.Final.jar
nimbus-jose-jwt-4.41.1.jar
paranamer-2.3.jar
protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar
snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
xmlenc-0.52.jar
xz-1.0.jar
zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
```

- I suspect these need to be included in PySpark application as well. It would be too long to download each `.jar` separately and probably is not the way to go.

**Attempted solution #2**

```py
builder = SparkSession.builder

builder = builder.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.5,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.5,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.10.6")

builder = builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
builder = builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
builder = builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"))
builder = builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))
builder = builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token", os.environ.get("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"))
```

- Instead of providing `jars` I use `--packages` it installs the dependencies as well. However, I end up with the following error when trying to read from S3:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterLong.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsInfo;J)V from class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation
...
```

**My research**

- [Spark uses s3a: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242548/spark-uses-s3a-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror)
- [NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities while reading s3 Data with spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310416/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-fs-streamcapabilities-while-reading-s3-d/52367502#52367502)
- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#java.lang.NoSuchMethodError_referencing_an_org.apache.hadoop_class

From that, I conclude that my problem has to do with `hadoop-aws` dependencies. However, I'm having a problem checking this. The versions of Hadoop running with Spark are the same as the jars that I use when connecting and I'm providing all the dependencies.

- Any tools or commands to run for debugging this issue would be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60484693/how-to-configure-spark-2-4-correctly-with-user-provided-hadoop

Comment: This looks promising. I will attempt this and update on results.

Comment: you're mixing hadoop-auth and hadoop-aws library versions.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I build spark 2.4.7 against hadoop 2.8.5 `./build/mvn -Phadoop2-8 -Dhadoop.version=2.8.5 -DskipTests clean package` and still got the same error with `method org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterLong`. This tells that the problem is with the way Pyspark installs `spark.jars.packages`. I will attempt dropping jars directly into spark install as you mentioned in the post and will keep you updated.

Comment: I was able to resolve this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67713127/when-writing-to-amazon-s3-using-pyspark-i-get-org-apache-hadoop-fs-streamcapabil. I think the problem was in Spark messing class paths somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an admin user in your S3 bucket and connect with the admin credentials instead of using a temporary connection.

https://bartek-blog.github.io/python/spark/2019/04/22/how-to-access-s3-from-pyspark.html

Comment: For my case, I need to use `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider`.

Comment: Also, the blog post that you linked is using `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem` instead of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`

Answer (score 0):

I found this code to help you from [this site](https://medium.com/@leythg/access-s3-using-pyspark-by-assuming-an-aws-role-9558dbef0b9e)

```
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=’MyUserProfile’)
sts_connection = session.client(‘sts’)
response = sts_connection.assume_role(RoleArn=’ARN_OF_THE_ROLE_TO_ASSUME’, RoleSessionName=’THIS_SESSIONS_NAME’,DurationSeconds=3600)
credentials = response[‘Credentials’]

url = str(‘s3a://bucket/key/data.csv’)

spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(‘fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider’, ‘org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider’)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(‘fs.s3a.access.key’, credentials[‘AccessKeyId’])
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(‘fs.s3a.secret.key’, credentials[‘SecretAccessKey’])
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(‘fs.s3a.session.token’, credentials[‘SessionToken’])
spark.read.csv(url).show(1)
```

Comment: `spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")`

is the same thing as 

`builder = builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")`

Comment: Also, the way you are getting credentials is not relevant for this question because the variables are coming from the env. And the error does not have anything to do with the validity of credentials.

Comment: The article suggests for `hadoop-3.1.2` adding these  `hadoop-aws-3.1.2.jar`
and `aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar` into spark jar directory. (I will try it tomorrow and update later).