# "Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support" error when trying to process hive table with spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I want to process hive table using spark, but when I run my program, I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.

##### My application code

```scala
object spark_on_hive_table extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Spark Hive Example")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hive/warehouse")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  spark.sql("select * from pbSales").show()

}
```

##### build.sbt

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.3.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.3.2" % "provided"
)
```

Comment: sparkVersion = ?

Comment: Sparkversion : 2.3.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create SparkSession with Hive support (fails with "Hive classes are not found")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444493/how-to-create-sparksession-with-hive-support-fails-with-hive-classes-are-not-f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove `provided` for your `spark-hive` dependency:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.3.2" % "provided"
```

change to

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.3.2"
```