# I am getting below error while compiling spark program in SBT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

Versions used:

Spark version: `2.3.2`

Scala version: `2.11.8`

SBT version: `1.2.4`

`build.sbt:`

```
name := "spark_demo"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql"  % "2.3.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive"  % "2.3.2"
)
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Based on your build logs and build.sbt content. It seems mismatch. You have mentioned scala Version as 2.11.8 but you build logs says scala-2.12

Comment: @RamdevSharma It's not version 2.12 but  name of folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scalac compile yields "object apache is not a member of package org"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269836/scalac-compile-yields-object-apache-is-not-a-member-of-package-org)

Comment: @PatrykRudnicki, in my local environment, folder name under target is created based on scala version. When I used scala version 2.11.X then folder was target/scala-2.11. This is why I suspected that this could be some issue with environment.