# Error using apache spark for scala in intelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to use apache spark in Scala in IntelliJ. I am importing spark like this

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.log4j._
```

however when I build my project I receive the error `object apache is not a member of package org import org.apache.spark._`

how can I fix this error?

Comment: Perhaps this post is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269836/scalac-compile-yields-object-apache-is-not-a-member-of-package-org

Comment: I've tried that solution, unfortunately it didn't help. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml file

Comment: what is your dependency manager (like maven/ gradle/ sbt)? Share the dependency file